# Why can't I use .value in a list using GetX?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm learning to use getx as Flutter state manager and I can't use .value in a list variable, even using .obs to make the list observable.

```
final List<TaskModel> _taskList = <TaskModel>[].obs;

  get taskList => this._taskList.**value**;
```

> The getter 'value' isn't defined for the type 'List'.

What is the correct way to do it with lists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lists are reactive (**Rx**) by default. Although you need to make them observable with `.obs`, you don't need to return `.value` in your getter.
Instead, you can directly return your private list:

```
get taskList => this._taskList;
```

And whenever your `_taskList` changes, it will automatically reflect on your observer widget (Obx, GetX).

Answer (score 0):

You Forget Add Import in the file .

```
import 'package:get/get.dart';
```

So Just Add this Line `.obs` Will Work.

Comment: I think he was having a different issue.